# Update Sitecore ImageField with Media Item from Content Hub

Tags: sitecore-api, content-hub, mediaurls

I'm writing a program that creates a new asset in Content Hub using the upload API. How do I attach that newly created asset to theImageField of an item in Sitecore. Most of the examples show how to create a new ImageField item using something from the media library but I haven't found anything using Content Hub. Here's the basics of what I've got so far which obviously doesn't work but it illustrates what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
using (new SecurityDisabler())   
{ 
    var providerItem= db.GetItem(this.SiteCorePath);
    if (providerItem.Empty) return false;

    this.providerItem.Fields.ReadAll();

    this.providerItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
    try
    {                    
        this.providerItem.Fields["SelectHealth Image"].Value = this.PublicUrl;
        this.providerItem.Editing.EndEdit();
    }
    catch
    {
        this.providerItem.Editing.CancelEdit();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured out how to solve this myself so I wanted to post this in case anyone else needs help with this. I realized that the FieldItems are just xml so I created a new ImageField and then added the attributes that I needed.

```
new ImageField(this.providerItem.Fields["Image"])
{
    Alt = this.ProviderName,
    LinkType = "external",
    Height = Height.ToString(),
    Width = Width.ToString()
};

ImageField imageField = (this.providerItem.Fields["Image"]);
imageField.SetAttribute("stylelabs-content-id", this.Entity.Entity.Id.ToString());
imageField.SetAttribute("thumbnailsrc", "https://contenthub-url/api/gateway/" + img.Id.ToString() + "/thumbnail");
imageField.SetAttribute("src", img.PublicLinkUrl);
imageField.SetAttribute("mediaid", "");
imageField.SetAttribute("stylelabs-content-type", "Image");

this.providerItem.Editing.EndEdit();
```